# How do you implement pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a function that takes plaintext like "HELLO" and a key like "YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO" (26 letters and each corresponds with a letter from the alphabet, so Y = A, T = B, etc.) as input and returns the encrypted version of the plaintext.

This is the function:

```
string encrypt(string plaintext, string key)
{
   string e_word; // encrypted text (ciphertext) that will be returned by the function
   int index;

   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
   {
    index = get_index(plaintext[i]); // index value is updated with every increment of the loop/ pass of the loop
    e_word = strcat(e_word, key[index]);
   }

   return e_word;
}
```

The error states "incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &" and occurs at the line below:

**e_word = strcat(e_word, key[index]);**

The error suggests a "&" is added right before "key[index]".
I am new to C and have been researching and playing around with pointers, but I am struggling to understand why a pointer is required in this context. However, I used a debugger and discovered that the index variable does indeed hold an int (like I want it to), but when it is used in "key[index]", "key[index]" returns a memory location (I believe). Why is this happening if I did not declare any pointers to hold the memory location of a variable?

Comment: You don't "implement" pointers in C, you use them. You only implement them if you're writing a compiler.

Comment: Is this actually C? Or something else? C does not have a `string` type.

Comment: I'm thinking wherever the problem was gotten from, did `typedef char* string;`

Comment: @JWCS Like cs50?

Comment: I've never learned that version, I'm only familiar with c89+

Comment: still, there is no such thing in the language as 'string'. Where did you get it from and how was it defined?

Comment: Is this a CS50 question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that somewhere you have `typedef char* string;`, defining your string to be an array/pointer of/to a bunch of char(acters), with the last one being the null terminator `'\0'`. Indexing into a string/char*/char[] retrieves just that `char`. If you want to pass in a string, aka a char* (char pointer) you have to give the address of it: `typeof(&key[i])` == `char*`, `typeof(key[i])` == `char`.

Your bigger problem is that passing in a single char does not have a following null char `'\0'`, it might concatenate garbage, since it's not a string. Your target `e_word` also doesn't have any size/memory given to it (C will not dynamically give you memory, usually). You can either just assign it a static size `char e_word[256] = {{0}}`, or in C99+, dynamically adjust `char e_word[strlen(plaintext)] = {{0}}`. In C, it may be more helpful to view operations as either reading/modifying data at a location or allocating memory in a location/variable.